# Deleting multiple table once in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i am trying to delete multiple table row from single query.

I am trying using

```
 $query="Delete from itineraries where itineraries_id='".$_REQUEST['id']."'
         Delete from itineraries_destination where itineraries_id='".$_REQUEST['id']."'
         Delete from itineraries_photo where itineraries_id='".$_REQUEST['id']."'";
```

But it's not working. Please Suggest me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql - delete from multiple tables with one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839905/mysql-delete-from-multiple-tables-with-one-query)

Comment: what duplicate? U suggest me an answer na

Comment: I have done it

My Query is

       $query = "Delete itineraries, itineraries_destination, itineraries_photo from itineraries INNER JOIN itineraries_destination INNER JOIN itineraries_photo  where itineraries.itineraries_id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."' And itineraries_destination.itineraries_id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."' And itineraries_photo.itineraries_id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."'";


Thanks all for replying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
Delete i, d, p
from itineraries i
inner join itineraries_destination d on d.itineraries_id = i.itineraries_id
inner join itineraries_photo p on p.itineraries_id = i.itineraries_id
where i.itineraries_id = $_REQUEST['id']
```

[SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fe5c/1)

Comment: *mumbles something about injection*

Comment: @MissRosy: you just saying 'not working' does not allow us to help you. Can you copy-paste what error MySQL gives you when you execute this query?

Comment: Thanks..I did it                                                            $query = "Delete itineraries, itineraries_destination, itineraries_photo from itineraries INNER JOIN itineraries_destination INNER JOIN itineraries_photo  where itineraries.itineraries_id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."' And itineraries_destination.itineraries_id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."' And itineraries_photo.itineraries_id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."'";

Comment: Like Konerak hinted: You should not just use user input in your query. It allows SQL injections and makes your code very vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

Its all in the manual [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html):

Multiple-table syntax:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

Or:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    FROM tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    USING table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

Comment: I have done it

My Query is

       $query = "Delete itineraries, itineraries_destination, itineraries_photo from itineraries INNER JOIN itineraries_destination INNER JOIN itineraries_photo  where itineraries.itineraries_id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."' And itineraries_destination.itineraries_id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."' And itineraries_photo.itineraries_id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."'";


Thanks all for replying

Answer (score 0):

1) You can only delete from one table with a single delete statement

2) The keyword FROM was missing - eg.

delete from test12 where ...

If you need to delete from mulitple tables, then is it possible to use a foreign key constraint with on delete cascade?

Failing that, I guess you are going to have to write a PL/SQL function to do the job.

Comment: Wrong. You can delete from multiple tables in one statement in MySQL. Checkout the [MySQL Manual, 13.2.2. DELETE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html): `Multiple-table syntax:`

Comment: but koneral for table references we should have foreign key between the tables.