# Using UNION in delete

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, union

I'm have 2 queries which I want to combine into one:

```
DELETE from #__gbl_ads where id in ($adid) AND user_id=$userid
```

and

```
DELETE from #__gbl_wishlist where ad_id in ($adid) AND userid=$userid
```

What I'm trying to write is:

```
DELETE from #__gbl_ads where id in ($adid) AND user_id=$userid UNION DELETE from #__gbl_wishlist where ad_id in ($adid) AND userid=$userid
```

but it doesn't seem to work... Could somebody help me please?

Comment: You need [*this answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4839931/767881) on SO.

Comment: Hi. thank you for the link, here is the code I tried but no success, did I write it correctly?

`DELETE id, ad_id FROM #__gbl_ads INNER JOIN #__gbl_wishlist WHERE id in ($adid) AND ad_id in ($adid)`

Comment: also tried `DELETE id, ad_id FROM #__gbl_ads INNER JOIN #__gbl_wishlist WHERE id=$adid AND ad_id=$adid`

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE from #__gbl_ads where id in ($adid) AND user_id=$userid;
DELETE from #__gbl_wishlist where ad_id in ($adid) AND userid=$userid;
```

use semi colons `";"` after each query.

Comment: I have an if statement saying:

`if (! $db->query ()) {
throw new DataException ( JText::_ ( "NO_DELETE1" ), 400 );`

Comment: @AlexandruVlas: what is the error message from the query? Also try to run this in your own sql environment and check whether that gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use UNION in delete statements.
UNION is supposed to be used with SELECT statements only

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine two `delete` statements on different tables. You could use a `where ... or` on the same table, but that's not the case here.

Comment: Do you need more help? If not, please close this question by marking it as answered.