# SQL DELETE not Deleting

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have this code

```
Const SQLStatement As String = "DELETE people, account FROM people CROSS JOIN account ON people.peopleID = account.peopleID WHERE uname = @p3 "
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", username.Value)
```

When the user inputs the ***username*** of an account, that statement should delete the records in two tables the `people table` and `account table`

It says that it is successful however when I look up to the database nothing has been changed?
I have another one which is add account however that works perfectly fine.

I don't know what is the problem? Is it in my syntax?

Comment: Use cascading to delete the `account` records when a `people` record is deleted. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4839927/3155705)

Comment: @LeeSalminen you can. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: @user2172157, what kind of error you getting and paste that error line

Comment: Sorry but I made a mistake, apparently it was the ID (primary key) that is causing the problem because the ID of two tables are different where they should be the same. I had to set the AUTO INCREMENT of two tables the same for the delete to happen. Thanks for helping everyone.