# Delete from 2 tables one-to-many relation

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have 3 tables: articles:

```
id title content date
```

tags:

```
id  name
```

tags_in_news:

```
id  news_id  tag_id
```

news_id is foreign key for articles table and tag_id is foreign key for tags tables...How to delete an article??
I tried but did not receive,my code:

```
$aid=(int)$this->uri->segment(3,0);
 $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM articles, tags_in_news WHERE articles.id = $aid AND tags_in_news.news_id = $aid ");
```

Help me please ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define foreign key constraints on the tables with `ON DELETE CASCADE` option.

Then deleting the record from parent table removes the records from child tables.

```
DELETE articles a ,tags_in_news t FROM articles INNER JOIN tags_in_news  WHERE a.id = t.id AND a.id = $aid
```

ref : [Mysql - delete from multiple tables with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839905/mysql-delete-from-multiple-tables-with-one-query?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DELETE a, tn 
FROM articles a INNER JOIN 
     tags_in_news  tn
WHERE a.id=tn.news_id 
    AND a.id = $aid 
    AND tn.news_id = $aid
```

**Another option:**

You can define foreign key constraints on the tables using `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Then deleting the record from parent table removes the records from child tables. Read more [**here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Credit: [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839905/mysql-delete-from-multiple-tables-with-one-query).

Comment: I define ON DELETE CASCADE