# Deleting multiple table using single Delete Statement

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables (for some reason I need to separate these to 3 tables, Im just joining them using LEFT JOIN)

table1

```
refno
location
```

table2

```
refno
description
```

table3

```
refno
imagepath
```

To delete, I need to issue 3 DELETE statements

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE refno = 'variablehere'
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE refno = 'variablehere'
DELETE FROM table3 WHERE refno = 'variablehere'
```

Is there a way to DELETE from the 3 tables using a single DELETE statement, I mean can I use something like LEFT JOIN in a DELETE Statement?

Comment: What will you be achieving by wanting to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql - delete from multiple tables with one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839905/mysql-delete-from-multiple-tables-with-one-query)

Comment: @SandeepRajoria. I just thought issuing 3 statements takes more load with my DB compared with issuing a single statement especially that Im deleting 5000+ rows per table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05e840/1/2) showing an example of the following query:

```
DELETE a.*, b.*, c.*
FROM table1 AS a, table2 AS b, table3 AS c
WHERE a.refno  = b.refno 
AND b.refno  = c.refno 
AND a.refno  = 'variablehere'
```