# Deleting from multiple MySQL Database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Why is it when I delete data from multiple tables in MySQL nothing happens? My scenario is when I delete a school from university all the courses, faculty and students enrolled in that school is also deleted.

Here's how I do it

```
DELETE FROM university, courses, faculty, students 
INNER JOIN university 
INNER JOIN courses 
INNER JOIN faculty 
INNER JOIN students ON university.id = courses.university_id
AND  courses.id = faculty.courses_id
AND faculty.id = students.faculty_id 
WHERE university.id = :id
```

WHERE `:id` = id from PHP code.

Reference: [Mysql - delete from multiple tables with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839905/mysql-delete-from-multiple-tables-with-one-query) and http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-statement.aspx

Comment: Why are you mixing join styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the syntax to use

```
DELETE university, courses, faculty, students 
FROM university 
INNER JOIN courses ON university.id = courses.university_id
INNER JOIN faculty ON courses.id = faculty.courses_id
INNER JOIN students ON faculty.id = students.faculty_id 
WHERE university.id = :id
```