# Delete data from multiple table using mysql(New Way)

Tags: php, mysql

I know that there is a lot of ways to delete data from mysql table using php, and also there is a lot of thread in this forum on 'how to delete data from mysql tables', but i want something else..

i use this query

```
$smt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM post,images WHERE post.Id=images.Id");
$smt->execute();
```

to get data from multiple mysql tables and it works  like charm, but when i try this query

```
$statement=$conn->prepare("DELETE FROM post,images WHERE post.Id=images.Id AND post.Id='".$id."'");
$statement->execute();
```

to delete data from multiple tables then it will not working, but if i tr like this

```
$statement=$conn->prepare("DELETE FROM post WHERE post.Id='".$id."'");
    $statement->execute();
```

then it will works fine and good, but i want to delete the data like the above way.....

Any help will be appreciated....

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839905/mysql-delete-from-multiple-tables-with-one-query

Comment: You need to write individual delete statements for each table or set up foreign key constraints with ON DELETE CASCADE option.