# mysqli - Delete method not deleting

Tags: php, mysqli

Got a delete method which is not working ... can anybody figure out why it's returning `0`? The item is present in the table.

```
public function deleteItem($item_id)
{
    $userItemIDS = array();

    $userItemIDS = $this->helperClass->userItemIDS();

    if( !in_array($item_id, $userItemIDS) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    $q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("DELETE i, s FROM items i
        LEFT JOIN save_list s
            ON i.id = s.item_id
        WHERE i.id = ? AND s.item_id = ?
        AND
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM pending_wins WHERE item_id = ?)
        AND
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM bids WHERE item_id = ?)");
    if($q)
    {
        $q->bind_param("iiii", $item_id, $item_id, $item_id, $item_id);
        $a_r = $q->affected_rows;
        $q->execute();
        $q->close();

        return $a_r;
    }
}
```

Comment: Either the query is not finding the rows, or your `prepare` is failing. You're not doing any error checking so you wouldn't know.

Comment: Pretty sure your query is wrong. Throw it in a try catch.

Comment: Not sure how to do any of those. Examples would help.

Comment: I just noticed that I didn't have `$q->execute();` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: before you do `$q->close();`, put this and let me know if anything shows up: `print_r($q->error);`. Also, you should read [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2553892/2518525) (*and be error handling like that*) for error reporting.

Comment: Nothing on that print_r

Comment: So I should do all those checks?

Comment: Error checking: check the return value of every call to MySQL for `false`. If it __is__ false, look at the appropriate error variable to find out what went wrong __and report it__. Right now you check the value of `$q`, and execute the query if it's not false. There's no reporting here so you have no way to know if the query executed or not.

Comment: @ciprian yes, all of those checks otherwise you won't know where it failed..

Comment: Also, your query is most likely (*90%*) failing because of your query: `DELETE i, s FROM....`, the syntax is `DELETE FROM table`, **not** `DELETE column_1,column_2 FROM table`....which means your query is wrong.

Comment: I keep finding queries built like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4839931/385623

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments are very helpful and I appreciate them a lot. However my problem was in the query itself. Taking out `AND s.item_id = ?` deletes the 
entry from the `items` table and from`save_list` if present.

```
 $q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("DELETE i, s FROM items i
    LEFT JOIN save_list s
        ON i.id = s.item_id
    WHERE i.id = ?
    AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM pending_wins WHERE item_id = ?)
    AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM bids WHERE item_id = ?)");
```