# Delete rows from multiple tables as one query

Tags: mysql

I am running following delete statements i want to know if it is possible at all to combine them somehow:

```
DELETE from schools where visibility like 'revoked'

DELETE FROM bookmark_schools
WHERE school_id NOT IN (SELECT s.id FROM school s)

DELETE FROM school_addresses 
WHERE school_id NOT IN (SELECT s.id FROM school s)

DELETE FROM school_highlights 
WHERE school_id NOT IN (SELECT s.id FROM school s)

DELETE FROM school_images 
WHERE school_id NOT IN (SELECT s.id FROM school s)
```

...

And so on i have like 15 queries like this. Is it possible to run them together rather than running them individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine them into a single statement as others have indicated, but note that this will still be a single threaded operation.

If your goal is to improve performance / parallelize this operation, you may want to write a script which creates the 15 different client threads to run the statements concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

ya it is possible,but one by one.but the question is whether you want to run it in the server or by some scripting language php.

Comment: I want to run it on server. I know it is possible to run it one by one. I am asking if it is possible to combine them all.

Comment: logically it is not possible,because u are doing operation on different table based on different condition

Answer (score 0):

You can join the query as below :

```
DELETE FROM bookmark_schools
FROM            bookmark_schools CROSS JOIN
                         school_addresses CROSS JOIN
                         school_highlights CROSS JOIN
                         school_images CROSS JOIN
                         schools CROSS JOIN
                         school
WHERE        (NOT (bookmark_schools.school_id IN
                             (SELECT        id
                               FROM            school AS s))) AND (NOT (school_addresses.school_id IN
                             (SELECT        id
                               FROM            school AS s))) AND (NOT (school_highlights.school_id IN
                             (SELECT        id
                               FROM            school AS s))) AND (NOT (school_images.school_id IN
                             (SELECT        id
                               FROM            school AS s))) AND (schools.visibility LIKE N'revoked')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want but with some conditions as per below-

step1: tables engine should be innodb as not work in myisam.

Step2: Make foreign key references means all child tables like bookmark_schools, school_Addresses etc. have a reference of master table schools with on delete cascade on.

Step3: Now you just need to delete rows from master table i.e. schools, and foreign key check will remove from all child tables.

Further you can take help from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Answer (score 0):

To delete rows from multiple tables using a single query you will have to create an `INNER JOIN` on two tables. Refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839905/mysql-delete-from-multiple-tables-with-one-query)