# PDO join statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following join below and I was wanting to know is there a better way to write it as I am getting `Unknown table 'id' in MULTI DELETE` and I cannot seem to pin point where.

**Join:**

```
$query = $dbConnection->prepare('
    DELETE c.id, r.id, s.id,f.id,ip.id,ct.id
    FROM campaigns c
    JOIN campaignsFroms f ON f.id = c.id
    JOIN campaignsRaw r ON r.id = c.id
    JOIN campaignsSubjects s ON s.id = c.id
    JOIN campaignIPTracking ip ON ip.id = c.id
    JOIN campaignTracking ct ON ct.id = c.id
    WHERE c.id = :campaign_id');
$query->execute(array(':campaign_id' => $campaign_id));
```

Comment: `DELETE` deletes rows. You need to omit fields. Also, if you want to delete row from one table by id you need to omit all other tables.

Comment: not really a duplicate but related and helpful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839905/mysql-delete-from-multiple-tables-with-one-query

Comment: [the docs are also helpful](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DELETE` statement is incorrect. You should remove the fields.

```
DELETE 
    FROM campaigns c
    JOIN campaignsFroms f ON f.id = c.id
    JOIN campaignsRaw r ON r.id = c.id
    JOIN campaignsSubjects s ON s.id = c.id
    JOIN campaignIPTracking ip ON ip.id = c.id
    JOIN campaignTracking ct ON ct.id = c.id
    WHERE c.id = :campaign_id'
```