# PHP/MySQL : How to delete all data from database which contains specific id in one query

Tags: php, mysql

In my database i have 32 tables, and most of the tables has contain same ids. How can I delete all the data in the whole database that contains only an specific ID in one query(I mean each tables that contain that specific id).

```
DELETE * from (ALL TABLES) where id = 3;
```

Comment: There's no shortcut. Could you be more specific about your use-case?

Comment: The only at least a little bit viable way would be to do `DELETE * FROM table1, table2, table3, etc WHERE table1.id = 3, table2.id = 3, table3.id = 3, etc;`

Comment: I tried inner join it works but yes can't find a shortcut way

Comment: Handling it in DB?: If you know this is always the case, you can set a table to be the "master" one. All the others with have FK to it along with `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Then you only delete the row from the master [(example)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839905/mysql-delete-from-multiple-tables-with-one-query)

Answer (score 2):

Good question. Query might be optimal solution for this.

I have give solutions using PHP here below as PHP tag specified by you

```
<?php
require("db_connect.php");
$tables = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW TABLES FROM dbname");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tables)) {
    $table_name = $row["Tables_in_dbname"];
    mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE `id`=3");
}
?>
```

OR

create one more table where you make daily entries for `id` which needed to delete from all tables and everyday you might get the different list of `id` to delete from all tables.

Below here i have created a table `ids_to_delete` where i specified list of ids to be deleted.

```
<?php
require("db_connect.php");
//get ids from table where specified ids to be deleted
$ids     = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `id` FROM `ids_to_delete`");
$id_list = '';
//create ids list like 1,4,3,9,5,6,...
while ($row_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tables)) {
    $id_list .= $row_id['id'] . ',';
}
$id_list = trim($id_list, ',');

$tables = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW TABLES FROM dbname");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tables)) {
    $table_name = $row["Tables_in_dbname"];
    mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE `id` IN ($id_list)");
}
//clear the ids_to_delete table
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM `ids_to_delete`");
?>
```

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.