# How to perform multiple delete query on multiple table at once

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I´m trying to delete multiple records on multiples tables at once

Using an sql script into php mysql_query function :

```
$sql= " delete from table1 where id = '$id';
        delete from table2 where id = '$id';
        delete from table3 where id = '$id';";
mysql_query($sql, $connect);
```

But it not seems to be working, is there some mistake ? Is there other way to do that ?

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: is there a reason you can't call it 3 times?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql - delete from multiple tables with one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839905/mysql-delete-from-multiple-tables-with-one-query)

Comment: Three tables? Three queries. Doing this as one big multi-query is a mistake.

Comment: @alex is right. There is another way also. i.e. to use foriegn key constraints on these tables and with the` on delete cascade ` option

Answer (score 0):

Try using a **transaction** , it will provide **atomicity, consistency , isolation and durability** out of the box and gives better result in terms of **performance** as well . AS far as **mysql** **API** is concerned try moving on to **PDO** or **MYSQLi** for that matter .