# Delete all rows with a specific ID from 3 different tables using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to remove all rows from three different tables that matches a specific ID.
All three tables uses the same ID: `chat_id`.

How do I delete all rows from three different tables WHERE `chat_id` = `1234`?

Example:
    `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('DELETE FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE chat_id = ?');`

I should mention that this is inside a loop see below.
My full code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT chat_id FROM chat_id WHERE chat_expire < NOW()');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $chatid[] = $row['chat_id'];
}
$stmt->close();

foreach($chatid as $id) { // Delete all old posts.
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('DELETE FROM chat_id, chat_msg, chat_nick WHERE chat_id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: You can't do it in a single DELETE statement. You'll need three. This is basic SQL, and has nothing to do with PHP. You may want to find a SQL tutorial or buy a book.

Comment: [Mysql - delete from multiple tables with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839905/mysql-delete-from-multiple-tables-with-one-query)

Comment: @KenWhite It can be done ^

Comment: @Fred-ii-: That's not what this question asks. The poster doesn't ask about how to structure constraints or triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the same query three times by changing the table name, always in the same function.