# Delete row from two tables with condition

Tags: mysql

My example:

Table A: post_id

Table B: id + delete(null)

- In that, **post_id = id**

I want to delete all rows for both tables **where A.deleted != 'null'**

I tried: `Delete A, B FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON B.post_id = A.id WHERE A.deleted != 'null'` - but not work

Comment: Check this article https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/

Comment: is it showing syntax error?
What is relation between `A` and `B`.
 can you share your data

Comment: I suggest first make working select query than make it delete query

Comment: @RaviMakwana I checked and try all example, it delete all my rows.
A & B have same id as I mention: post_id from A, id from B sir

Comment: I mean is it **one to one** or **one to many** relation in that case you can use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`

Comment: @RaviMakwana sorry, I write mistake, it should be A.deleted != 'null'. So when I run: **Delete A, B FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON B.post_id = A.id WHERE A.deleted != 'null'** - it remove nearly all my row

Comment: oh man, that's why mostly suggest to first create Select Query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql - delete from multiple tables with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839905/mysql-delete-from-multiple-tables-with-one-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your no record fetch for `delete != 'null'` then you should add `deleted is not null OR delete != 'null'`

You can not check null value with `==` or `!=` operator you need to use `is` or `is not` for this kind of filtration

```
Delete A, B 
    FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON B.post_id = A.id 
    WHERE  A.deleted is not null OR A.deleted != 'null'
```

Comment: Thank you for support, it should be A.deleted not B.deleted in my case, working now !

Comment: Great, You know the batter :D