# How delete rowns in tables with foreign key without enabling CASCADE DELETE in MySQL 5.X

Tags: mysql

[This image show the database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgSyX.jpg)

```
SET  @ID = (SELECT ID FROM pessoa WHERE CPF=123456);
SET  @ID = (SELECT ENDERECO FROM pessoa WHERE CPF=123456);
SET @TELEFONES = (SELECT ID_TELEFONE FROM pessoa_telefone WHERE ID_PESSOA=@ID);
SET @TIPOS = (SELECT TIPO FROM telefone WHERE ID IN (@TELEFONES));

DELETE FROM pessoa_telefone WHERE ID_PESSOA=@ID;

DELETE FROM pessoa WHERE ID=@ID;
DELETE FROM endereco WHERE ID=@ENDERECO;

DELETE FROM telefone WHERE ID IN (@TELEFONES);
DELETE FROM telefone_tipo WHERE ID IN (@TIPOS);
```

This code works, but how reduce to something like this:

```
DELETE FROM pessoa_telefone, pessoa, endereco, telefone, telefone_tipo
JOIN pessoa, JOIN endereco,
JOIN telefone, JOIN telefone_tipo
ON pessoa_telefone.ID_PESSOA = pessoa.ID
ON pessoa.ENDERECO = endereco.ID
ON telefone.TIPO = telefone_tipo.ID
WHERE pessoa.CPF = 123456
```

Comment: The code that you say "works" would fail with syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MySQL 5.7 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) you can use multiple-table delete if ***not using*** InnoDB tables (for which there are foreign key constraints).

In this case, the code below should work:

```
delete pt, p, t, tp, e
from pessoa_telefone pt 
inner join pessoa p on p.id = pt.id_pessoa
inner join telefone t on t.id = pt.id_telefone
inner join telefone_tipo tp on tp.id = t.tipo
inner join endereco e on e.id = p.endereco
where p.cpf = '123456';
```

If you are ***using*** InnoDB (tables for which there are foreign key constraints), again according to the [MySQL 5.7 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html): *"you should delete from a single table and rely on the ON DELETE capabilities that InnoDB provides to cause the other tables to be modified accordingly"*.

Also, there are many other questions like that on stack overflow. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839905/mysql-delete-from-multiple-tables-with-one-query/29159168) (already marked as duplicated).

Comment: I'm using InnoDB with foreign key that show the diagram, but the ON DELETE is RESTRICT. Changing the ON DELETE is not a option to CASCADE.